# How do I Configure a Docker Registry V2 with Apache and a CA certificate?

Tags: apache, docker, certificate, docker-registry

I have read all the references here and out on a google search and have been unable to get my registry accessible using a CA signed certificate. Here is what I have:

Apache proxy (have tried various configs, none of which have any effect to docker):

> listen dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000 https
>   ServerName dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com
>
> SSLEngine on
>       SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA,AES256-SHA,AES128-GCM-SHA256,AES256-GCM-SHA384
>       SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1
>
> ```
> Header always set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
> Header onsuccess set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
> RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
>
> ProxyPreserveHost on
> ProxyPass   /v2 http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
> ProxyPassReverse /v2  http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
> ```
>
> SSLEngine on
>       SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/DockerRepoCAKeyCert.crt
>       SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA,AES256-SHA,AES128-GCM-SHA256,AES256-GCM-SHA384
>       SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1
>
> ```
> Header always set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
> Header onsuccess set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
> RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
>
> ProxyPreserveHost on
> ProxyPass   /v2 http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
> ProxyPassReverse /v2  http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2
> ```

I start the registry:

> prod=registry
>   ver=2.1.1
>   docker load --input /home/docker/docker_${prod}-${ver}.tar
>   docker run -d --privileged=true -e GUNICORN_OPTS="[--preload]" -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 --restart=always -v /home/docker/certs:/ce
>   rts -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/DockerRepoCACert.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/client-private-key-nopassphrase
>   .pem -v /home/docker/prodRepo/data:/tmp/registry-dev --name docker-registry ${prod}:${ver}

Registry and apache start fine. when I push I get this:

> [root@dockerrepo dockerrepo:5000]# docker push dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000/registry:2.1.1
>
> The push refers to a repository [dockerrepo.internal.acp.arris.com:5000/registry] (len: 1)
>
> unable to ping registry endpoint https://dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000/v0/
>
> v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https: //dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.com:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by 
>   unknown authority
>
> v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https: //dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I have tried combining the domain, intermediate/sub and root certs in all combinations, but I can't seem to get this to work. I suspect I am doing something silly, but I can't see what. Any help is appreciated.

After checking, I realized I had not added my cert to the CA trust. After doing this, I now get this error:

> [root@dockerrepo anchors]# docker push dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000/registry:2.1.1
>
> The push refers to a repository [dockerrepo.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5000/registry] (len: 1)
>
> 1e847b14150e: Buffering to Disk
>
> Received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Proxy Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the CA certificate is in the following directory on the host?

```
   /etc/docker/certs.d/<registry-host>:<registry-port>/
```